# ember-bootstrap: after installing ember-power-select popovers not working correctly

Tags: ember.js, ember-bootstrap, ember-power-select

I created a new project with ember-4.12.1 and installed ember-bootstrap (5.1.1). When I use the BsPopover component it is working as expected.

After installing ember-power-select (6.0.1) the popover is not displayed near the corospending object. The popover is displayed at the beginning of the page.

Any hints how I got ember-bootstrap & ember-power-select work together?

best regards, arno

I created a fresh poject and installed ember-bootstrap and created a page with the BsPopover component - all works as expected. Then I installed ember-power-select and at the same page the popover wasn't displayed near the corresponding object but at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arno, you have stumbled into a legit bug!

I have tried reproducing your steps and was able to see the failure.

I have reported the bug here for you, with screenshots and links to my reproduction:
https://github.com/ember-bootstrap/ember-bootstrap/issues/1939

Please follow it. If you're blocked on it, consider pinging `@Simon Ihmig` on the [#e-bootstrap](https://discord.com/channels/480462759797063690/485923967148883998) channel on EmberJS Discord ([invite](https://discord.com/invite/emberjs)).

Comment: Much thanks for reporting the bug an making the screenshots.

Comment: @ArnoSchneider Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you believe it's helpful and relevant.

Comment: As a workaround, consider pinning the version of `ember-modifier` (see the GitHub issue). Pinning varies depending on the package manager you're using.

Comment: with ember-bootstrap 6.0.0-2 ember-popper-modifier v3 is used and the bug disappears. Thanks! To upvote your answer the reputaion of my account is to low.